# See last modification in Google Drive/Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

In my Google Drive I see when a spreadsheet was modified:

[image: Last modification date of a spreadsheet in Google Drive]

How to go about seeing what the modification was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the spreadsheet
2. Next to the menus should be a link labeled "All changes saved in Drive". (This message will be different if GDrive is actively saving the document.

   - If you hover over the link you'll see when the last change was

   [image: "All changes saved in Drive"]
3. Click the link to open the change log. You'll get a list of dates on the right side, along with the name of the person who made each change.
4. Click on a date and the changes made by that person will be highlighted using the color of their icon.
   [image: Spreadsheet with change log]

More information at [Google Support: Revision history](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843)